# No route matches [PATCH] "/blog_posts/id/1/hide"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/blog_posts/id/1/hide"
```

in a scenario where I'm sure everything's correct. What's wrong with my code?

The route

```
patch '/blog_posts/:id/hide(.:format)', to: 'blog_posts#hide'
```

and the link

```
<%= link_to 'Hide', "/blog_posts/id/#{blog_post.id}/hide", method: :patch, data: 
        { confirm: 'Are you sure to hide this post?' } %>
```

The route is even listed on the error page printing all available routes...

```
    PATCH   /blog_posts/:id/hide(.:format)  blog_posts#hide
```

Comment: *"in a scenario where I'm sure everything's correct."* -- well, your path in the link indeed does not match the one you have specified. Take a closer look at it.

Comment: You should not generally have to build URLs like this, you should prefer the path helpers Rails gives you: `<%= link_to hide_blog_post_path(blog_post), ... %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"/blog_posts/id/1/hide"
```

does not equal

```
/blog_posts/1/hide
```

The latter is what the path should be.